# SSRS - How to group multiple tables in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

hello Im having trouble grouping two tables with different datasets in SSRS. each table has one common column which is the plan. Types of plan are  Plan 1, Plan 2 and Plan 3. I already created a parameter also which you can select the plan you want to show. Here's a sample of how it should look like once i click view report.

Table 1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Zie.png

Table 2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4u8D.png

Comment: so - what is the problem again?

Comment: I have two tables in the report with one common column which is the plan name. how can i group it that if i choose Plan 1 in the parameter, all plan 1 details in column 1 and column 2 will display?

Comment: Did you just want to filter the results in the two tables based on the parameter? It's not clear what you mean by "Group" them. Did you want to combine the results in the two tables as one table based on your parameter? If it is the former, just look at implementing filters on your table, if it's the later, then search for Lookup in SSRS

Comment: Please also mention the version on which you are working

Comment: Hi @Harry,
Did you just want to filter the results in the two tables based on the parameter?>>yes.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Group" them.>> I dont know if i was right but i mean like can i group the two tables with separately? like the have the same parent?

Comment: Did you want to combine the results in the two tables as one table based on your parameter?>> no need to combine. 2 tables must be separate tables.

Comment: @Athar hello, im using VS 2019 for my ssrs.

Comment: Go to table properties - Filters - Add - > For Expression: Select your Field that has Plan 1 For Operator set =, for Value Click on the Fx button to the right of the cell, set it to the parameter. Do the same for both tables.. done